# How to create a send button which downloads at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to create an input send and that when I click, it must automatically download a file on the computer and not that it opens a page etc..

Here is the code I would like to merge:

```
 <a href="/public/img/cv-Ornella.pdf"><button type="send" class="btn btn-outline-info"  action="/cv">telécharger !</button></a>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just add the attribute download to that anchor tag

Comment: thank you, I add it but it doesn't work: / the "send" type button works fine but it doesn't want to download: /

Comment: Buttons don't have send types nor action attributes

Comment: yes it is correct I have rectified by putting the type in submit and the button in input, but that creates 2 different buttons for me while I want all the 2 functionality in a single

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You can not have a `<button>` inside the `<a>` tag

Comment: how can I do it then?

Comment: I honestly don‘t understand your question. I don’t understand what you want to „send“!? For me you download a file which is one thing. Then you write something about an input, but there is no input...

Comment: I created a mongodb collection from which I only collect the date from the computer.
and this action i would like that when the user clicks the download button, it executes my post request.
But I don't arrive after several hours, seems like it's not possible